# What is signified by the use of a "big" integral sign? [photo example]

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

I encountered what I'll call, for lack of a better term, a "big" integral sign in a generic form of Integral Product Rule. I call it "big" relative to those preceding, and especially to the one immediately following it, in this example. This notation is strange (unfamiliar) to me. Please share your experience with this symbol.

[image: Use of the "big" integral sign, in an explanation of Integral Product Rule]

Comment: That appears to be nothing more than sloppy handwriting, or a larger symbol to distinguish it from the integral which follows (which appears to apply only to $f$).

Comment: Instead of $\int f$, write $F$ (see a few lines above) and then $\int fg=Fg-\int Fg'$ is clear enough without the need to use different sizes of integral signs for suggestivitiy. The formulae are still sloppy (probably missing $\mathrm dx$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the integration-by-parts formula, although demonstrated in a quite confusing way. Especially, it is unclear which function $\int$ is applied to. Using parentheses to emphasize the scope of $\int$ for each instance, we may instead write

$$\int(fg) = \left(\int f\right) g - \int \left(\left( \int f \right) g'\right). $$

It is still an unconventional way of demonstrating the IbP formula. So let me revert it to the good old way. Let $F $ denote an anti-derivative of $f$, i.e., $F' = f$. Then

$$ \int f(x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = F(x)g(x) - \int F(x)g'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Alternatively, it may help to adopt programmer-style notation for this. Write $\mathtt{Integrate}[f]$ for any ani-derivative of $f$ and $\mathtt{D}[g]$ for the derivative $g'$. Then the handwriting translates to

$$ \mathtt{Integrate}[f \cdot g] = \mathtt{Integrate}[f] \cdot g - \mathtt{Integrate}[\mathtt{Integrate}[f] \cdot \mathtt{D}[g]]. $$

Answer (score 2):

He is writing an integral of a product, and the two factors are $\int f$ and $g'$.  So he wrote the outside integral bigger.

$$
\int\;{\textstyle \int f} \cdot g'
$$